# More efficient way to extract and subtract rows R in different dataframes

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, for-loop, bigdata

I am working with this basketball game data with a dataframe games with around 50,000 rows. I am trying to compare the stats of each team ( A and B) in each game.

I have another dataframe called teamStats that has around 3000 rows each with teams from every season.

So far, I have assembled a code as the following:

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(games)) {
  if (length(which(((teamStats$Year == games$Season[i])==1) & (teamStats$teamID == games$teamA[i]))) == 1) {
    selectTeamA <- teamStats[which(((teamStats$Year == games$Season[i])==1) & (teamStats$teamID == games$teamA[i])),4:45]
  } else {
    selectTeamA <- as.numeric(rep(NA, ncol(differences)))
  }
  if (length(which(((teamStats$Year == games$Season[i])==1) & (teamStats$teamID == games$teamB[i]))) == 1) {
    selectTeamB <- teamStats[which(((teamStats$Year == games$Season[i])==1) & (teamStats$teamID == games$teamB[i])),4:45]
  } else {
    selectTeamB <- as.numeric(rep(NA, ncol(differences)))
  }

  differences[i,] <- selectTeamA - selectTeamB
}
```

Basically, this code searches for the correct teamID for each team A and B, after subsetting the correct season. Since every team for every season is not present in the teamstats, I have filled the missing rows with NA's for now. The "differences" dataframe is an empty dataframe that will be filled my the differences of stats of team A and B from the for loop.

To give you an idea of the data:

Games - first 6 rows

```
           Season teamA teamB winner scoreA scoreB
108123   2010  1143  1293      A     75     70
108124   2010  1198  1314      B     72     88
108125   2010  1108  1326      B     60    100
108126   2010  1107  1393      B     43     75
108127   2010  1143  1178      A     95     61
```

teamStats - first 6 rows and only first 6 columns for space - lot of columns with different stats in full dataframe. The code finds the correct row for the teamID and then substracts the stat columns such as G W L etc

```
              School Year teamID  G  W  L
1  abilene christian 2018   1101 32 16 16
2          air force 2018   1102 31 12 19
3              akron 2018   1103 32 14 18
4        alabama a&m 2018   1105 31  3 28
5 alabama-birmingham 2018   1412 33 20 13
```

And to close this very long post, my question. My for loop code works and fills the differences dataframe. The issue is it takes 20-30 minutes to run this code. I am not very experienced working with this much data. Is there a technique I don't know? How can I rewrite this code in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` packages that I expect should be much faster than the loop solution in the OP. The speed (I expect) comes from relying more on database join operations (base `merge` or dplyr's `left_join`, for example) to connect the two tables.

```
library(tidyverse)

# First, use the first few columns from the `games` table, and convert to long format with
#   a row for each team, and a label column `team_cat` telling us if it's a teamA or teamB.
stat_differences <- games %>%
  select(row, Season, teamA, teamB)  %>% 
  gather(team_cat, teamID, teamA:teamB) %>%  

# Join to the teamStats table to bring in the team's total stats for that year
  left_join(teamStats %>% select(-row),    # We don't care about this "row"
            by = c("teamID", "Season" = "Year")) %>%

# Now I want to reverse the stats' sign if it's a teamB. To make this simpler, I gather
#   all the stats into long format so that we can do the reversal on all of them, and 
#   then spread back out.
  gather(stat, value, G:L) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(team_cat == "teamB", value * -1, value * 1)) %>%
  spread(stat, value) %>%

# Get the difference in stats for each row in the original games table.
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(G:W), sum)

# Finally, add the output to the original table
output <- games %>% 
  left_join(stat_differences)
```

To test this, I altered the given sample data so that the two tables would relate to each other:

```
games <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "row           Season teamA teamB winner scoreA scoreB
108123   2010  1143  1293      A     75     70
108124   2010  1198  1314      B     72     88
108125   2010  1108  1326      B     60    100")

teamStats <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "row   School Year teamID  G  W  L
1  abilene_christian 2010   1143 32 16 16
2          air_force 2010   1293 31 12 19
3              akron 2010   1314 32 14 18
4        alabama_a&m 2010   1198 31  3 28
5 alabama-birmingham 2010   1108 33 20 13
6       made_up_team 2018   1326 160 150 10    # To confirm getting right season
7       made_up_team 2010   1326 60 50 10"
)
```

Then I get the following output, which seems to make sense.
(I just realized that the gather/mutate/spread I applied changed the order of the columns; if I have time I might try to use a mutate_if to preserve the order.)

```
> output
     row Season teamA teamB winner scoreA scoreB   G  L   W
1 108123   2010  1143  1293      A     75     70   1 -3   4
2 108124   2010  1198  1314      B     72     88  -1 10 -11
3 108125   2010  1108  1326      B     60    100 -27  3 -30
```

Comment: Forgive me but I am trying this code but I keep getting errors... 
`Error: row must resolve to integer column positions, not a function
Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'stat_differences' not found .` Its probably me not understanding what you are doing fully, but do you have any help?

Comment: In my example code, I imported the leftmost unnamed column from your example as  a column called "row." I think the error is noting that a column with that name wasn't found in your data. It will be useful to make one. You could add `mutate(row = row_number()) %>%` in between the `stat_differences <- games %>%` and 
  `select(row, Season, teamA, teamB)  %>%` lines.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to merge `games` and `teamStats`, as an alternative to iterating across rows.

Some code to replicate your set-up, to create a minimal working example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)
n_games <- 50000
n_teams <- 400
n_years <- 10

games <- data.frame(Season = rep(2005:(2005 + n_years - 1),
                                 each = n_games / n_years)) %>%
  mutate(teamA = sample(1000:(1000 + n_teams - 1), n_games, r = TRUE),
         teamB = map_int(teamA, ~sample(setdiff(1000:(1000 + n_teams - 1), .), 1)),
         scoreA = as.integer(rnorm(n_games, 80, 20)),
         scoreB = as.integer(rnorm(n_games, 80, 20)),
         scoreB = ifelse(scoreA == scoreB, scoreA + sample(c(-1, 1), n_games, r = TRUE), scoreB),
         winner = ifelse(scoreA > scoreB, "A", "B"))

gen_random_string <- function(...) {
  paste(sample(c(letters, " "), rpois(1, 10), r = TRUE), collapse = "")
}

schools_ids <- data.frame(teamID = 1000:(1000 + n_teams - 1)) %>%
  mutate(School = map_chr(teamID, gen_random_string))

teamStats <- data.frame(Year = rep(2005:(2005 + n_years - 1), each = 300)) %>%
  mutate(teamID = as.vector(replicate(n_years, sample(schools_ids$teamID, 300))),
         G = 32, W = rpois(length(teamID), 16), L = G - W) %>%
  left_join(schools_ids)
```

We have `games` with 50k rows and teamStats with 3k rows. Now, we collapse `teamStats` into a tibble by `Year` and `teamID`:

```
teamStats <- teamStats %>%
  group_by(Year, teamID) %>%
  nest()

# # A tibble: 3,000 x 3
#     Year teamID data            
#    <int>  <int> <list>          
#  1  2005   1321 <tibble [1 x 4]>
#  2  2005   1192 <tibble [1 x 4]>
#  3  2005   1074 <tibble [1 x 4]>
# <snip>
```

Make a small convenience function to calculate differences:

```
calculate_diff <- function(x, y) {
  if (is.null(x) | is.null(y)) {
    data.frame(G = NA, W = NA, L = NA)
  } else {
    x[, 1:3] - y[, 1:3]
  }
}
```

Now, we (1) join (or merge) `games` with `teamStats`, (2) calculate differences using the joined dataset, and (3) `unnest` (or un-collapse) the dataframe.

```
start <- Sys.time()
differences <- games %>%
  left_join(teamStats, c("Season" = "Year", "teamA" = "teamID")) %>%
  rename(teamA_stats = data) %>%
  left_join(teamStats, c("Season" = "Year", "teamB" = "teamID")) %>%
  rename(teamB_stats = data) %>%
  mutate(diff = map2(teamA_stats, teamB_stats, calculate_diff)) %>%
  select(Season, teamA, teamB, diff) %>%
  unnest()
difftime(Sys.time(), start)
# Time difference of 11.27832 secs
```

with the result

```
head(differences)
#   Season teamA teamB  G  W  L
# 1   2005  1115  1085 NA NA NA
# 2   2005  1315  1177 NA NA NA
# 3   2005  1163  1051  0 -9  9
# 4   2005  1353  1190  0 -4  4
# 5   2005  1376  1286 NA NA NA
# 6   2005  1018  1362  0 -1  1
```